# Not receiving the parameters containing '?' properly. The part after '?' is getting trimmed. How do I avoid it?

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-urls

I am writing a Django application. In my 'urls.py' I have written a URL pattern like this:

```
url(r'^rest/post/(.*)/$', rest_post),
```

Now when I am passing some URL like:

```
http://www.google.com/a?b
```

In my `rest_post` view I am getting only: `http://www.google.com/a`

I want to get the full URL. How do I do it?

Comment: Most people would consider your `a` and your `b` very different things (path and search string, respectively). URL matching is normally done on URLs up to but not including the search string.

Comment: @Amadan Actually I am building a URL shortener. So I need to pass the URL to my views in order to process it. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: See the linked question on how to get the original request path; or you can see [other methods of `request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) for fetching any other request datum.

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
request.get_full_path()
```

in your views.

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path

Comment: Cool it works! 
Note: But then I was getting "/rest/post/http://www.google.com/a/?b". 
So I manually trimmed off the first part like this: 
request.get_full_path()[11:]

Comment: No. I want to get "http://www.google.com/a?b". That is, the whole parameter that was passed.

Comment: @anirban.at.web ok got you